# Java: Enum or encoding with numbers?

Tags: java, iteration

I am starting to learn Java and I'd like to try to test out a few Java features by writing a simple program that will build an array of a deck of cards and will print out a list of all the cards. When I started doing this I was unsure whether it is more efficient to use numbers to represent the cards suits and ranks or to use enums. I'd like to know which is better in terms of efficiency, readability and convention? Which is better for iteration? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the two code variants that you're considering.  Then we can comment on them directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Readability**: Enums

**Convention**: Enums

**Efficiency**: You shouldn't care until you know you have a problem. It is very unlikely that you will ever encounter a performance problem due to the use of Enums.

Comment: 1+ for good points. Only downside I can think of with enums is a lack of extensibility.

Answer (score 1):

i used enums for rank, suit, and card.

```
package sample;
import java.util.*;
enum Rank { 
    joker(new Character('*'),"Joker"),aceLow(new Character('a'),"Ace(low)"),deuce(new Character('2'),"Deuce"),trey(new Character('3'),"Trey"),four(new Character('4'),"Four"),five(new Character('5'),"Five"),six(new Character('6'),"Six"),seven(new Character('7'),"Seven"),eight(new Character('8'),"Eight"),nine(new Character('9'),"Nine"),ten(new Character('T'),"Ten"),jack(new Character('J'),"Jack"),queen(new Character('Q'),"Queen"),king(new Character('K'),"King"),aceHigh(new Character('A'),"Ace");
    Rank(final Character c,final String s) {
        this.c=c;
        this.s=s;
    }
    public static Rank fromInt(int n) {
        for(Rank r:Rank.values())
            if(r.ordinal()==n)
                return r;
        return null;
    }
    public static Rank fromCharacter(char c) {
        for(Rank r:Rank.values())
            if(r.c==c)
                return r;
        return null;
    }
    public static Rank[] fromCharacters(final String cards) {
        final Rank[] rank=new Rank[5];
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            rank[i]=Rank.fromCharacter(cards.charAt(i));
        return rank;
    }
    public Character toCharacter() {
        return c;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return s;
    }
    public static String toString(final Rank[] rank) {
        String s="";
        for(Rank r:rank)
            s+=r.toCharacter();
        return s;
    }
    final Character c;
    final String s;
}
enum Suit {
    joker(new Character('*'),"Joker"),clubs(new Character('c'/* try character for a real dimond? */),"Club"),diamonds(new Character('d'),"Diamond"),hearts(new Character('h'),"Heart"),spades(new Character('s'),"Spade");
    Suit(final Character c,final String s) {
        this.c=c;
        this.s=s;
    }
    public static Suit fromCharacter(char c) {
        for(Suit s:Suit.values())
            if(s.c==c)
                return s;
        return null;
    }
    public Character toCharacter() {
        return c;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return s;
    }
    public static String toString(final Suit[] suit) {
        String s_="";
        for(Suit s:suit)
            s_+=s.toCharacter();
        return s_;
    }
    public static boolean areSuited(final Suit[] suit) {
        final int n=suit.length;
        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
            if(suit[i]!=suit[i+1])
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    final Character c;
    final String s;
}
enum Card {
    joker(Rank.joker,Suit.joker),
    aceLowOfClubs(Rank.aceLow,Suit.clubs),
    aceLowOfDiamonds(Rank.aceLow,Suit.diamonds),
    aceLowOfHearts(Rank.aceLow,Suit.hearts),
    aceLowOfSpades(Rank.aceLow,Suit.spades),
    dueceOfClubs(Rank.deuce,Suit.clubs),
    dueceOfDiamonds(Rank.deuce,Suit.diamonds),
    dueceOfHearts(Rank.deuce,Suit.hearts),
    dueceOfSpades(Rank.deuce,Suit.spades),
    treyOfClubs(Rank.trey,Suit.clubs),
    treyOfDiamonds(Rank.trey,Suit.diamonds),
    treyOfHearts(Rank.trey,Suit.hearts),
    treyOfSpades(Rank.trey,Suit.spades),
    fourOfClubs(Rank.four,Suit.clubs),
    fourOfDiamonds(Rank.four,Suit.diamonds),
    fourOfHearts(Rank.four,Suit.hearts),
    fourOfSpades(Rank.four,Suit.spades),
    fiveOfClubs(Rank.five,Suit.clubs),
    fiveOfDiamonds(Rank.five,Suit.diamonds),
    fiveOfHearts(Rank.five,Suit.hearts),
    fiveOfSpades(Rank.five,Suit.spades),
    sixOfClubs(Rank.six,Suit.clubs),
    sixOfDiamonds(Rank.six,Suit.diamonds),
    sixOfHearts(Rank.six,Suit.hearts),
    sixOfSpades(Rank.six,Suit.spades),
    sevenOfClubs(Rank.seven,Suit.clubs),
    sevenOfDiamonds(Rank.seven,Suit.diamonds),
    sevenOfHearts(Rank.seven,Suit.hearts),
    sevenOfSpades(Rank.seven,Suit.spades),
    eightOfClubs(Rank.eight,Suit.clubs),
    eightOfDiamonds(Rank.eight,Suit.diamonds),
    eightOfHearts(Rank.eight,Suit.hearts),
    eightOfSpades(Rank.eight,Suit.spades),
    nineOfClubs(Rank.nine,Suit.clubs),
    nineOfDiamonds(Rank.nine,Suit.diamonds),
    nineOfHearts(Rank.nine,Suit.hearts),
    nineOfSpades(Rank.nine,Suit.spades),
    tenOfClubs(Rank.ten,Suit.clubs),
    tenOfDiamonds(Rank.ten,Suit.diamonds),
    tenOfHearts(Rank.ten,Suit.hearts),
    tenOfSpades(Rank.ten,Suit.spades),
    jackOfClubs(Rank.jack,Suit.clubs),
    jackOfDiamonds(Rank.jack,Suit.diamonds),
    jackOfHearts(Rank.jack,Suit.hearts),
    jackOfSpades(Rank.jack,Suit.spades),
    queenOfClubs(Rank.queen,Suit.clubs),
    queenOfDiamonds(Rank.queen,Suit.diamonds),
    queenOfHearts(Rank.queen,Suit.hearts),
    queenOfSpades(Rank.queen,Suit.spades),
    kingOfClubs(Rank.king,Suit.clubs),
    kingOfDiamonds(Rank.king,Suit.diamonds),
    kingOfHearts(Rank.king,Suit.hearts),
    kingOfSpades(Rank.king,Suit.spades),
    aceOfClubs(Rank.aceHigh,Suit.clubs),
    aceOfDiamonds(Rank.aceHigh,Suit.diamonds),
    aceOfHearts(Rank.aceHigh,Suit.hearts),
    aceOfSpades(Rank.aceHigh,Suit.spades);
    private Card(Rank rank,Suit suit) {
        this.rank=rank;
        this.suit=suit;
    }

    public Rank rank() {
        return rank;
    }
    public Suit suit() {
        return suit;
    }
    public String toString() {
        if(rank.equals(Rank.joker)||suit.equals(Suit.joker))
            return "Joker";
        else return rank+" of "+suit+'s';
    }
    public static String toString(final Card[] card) {
        String s=new String();
        for(int i=0;i<card.length;i++) {
            if(i>0)
                s+=", ";
            s+=card[i].toCharacters();
        }
        return s;
    }
    public String toCharacters() {
        return ""+rank().toCharacter()+suit().toCharacter();
    }
    public static Card instance(Rank rank,Suit suit) { // some hack for speed
        final int n=4*rank.ordinal()+suit.ordinal();
        //System.out.println(rank+" "+suit+" "+n);
        return element[4*rank.ordinal()+suit.ordinal()];
    }
    static Card[] create(int standards,int jokers) {
        int cards=0;
        Card card[]=new Card[standards*52+jokers];
        for(int i=0;i<standards;i++)
            for(Suit suit:EnumSet.range(Suit.clubs,Suit.spades))
                for(Rank rank:EnumSet.range(Rank.deuce,Rank.aceHigh))
                    card[cards++]=instance(rank,suit);
        for(int i=0;i<jokers;i++)
            card[cards++]=instance(Rank.joker,Suit.joker);
        return card;
    }
    private final Rank rank;
    private final Suit suit;
    private static final Card element[]={joker,joker,joker,joker,joker,aceLowOfClubs,aceLowOfDiamonds,aceLowOfHearts,aceLowOfSpades,dueceOfClubs,dueceOfDiamonds,dueceOfHearts,dueceOfSpades,treyOfClubs,treyOfDiamonds,treyOfHearts,treyOfSpades,fourOfClubs,fourOfDiamonds,fourOfHearts,fourOfSpades,fiveOfClubs,fiveOfDiamonds,fiveOfHearts,fiveOfSpades,sixOfClubs,sixOfDiamonds,sixOfHearts,sixOfSpades,sevenOfClubs,sevenOfDiamonds,sevenOfHearts,sevenOfSpades,eightOfClubs,eightOfDiamonds,eightOfHearts,eightOfSpades,nineOfClubs,nineOfDiamonds,nineOfHearts,nineOfSpades,tenOfClubs,tenOfDiamonds,tenOfHearts,tenOfSpades,jackOfClubs,jackOfDiamonds,jackOfHearts,jackOfSpades,queenOfClubs,queenOfDiamonds,queenOfHearts,queenOfSpades,kingOfClubs,kingOfDiamonds,kingOfHearts,kingOfSpades,aceOfClubs,
        aceOfDiamonds,aceOfHearts,aceOfSpades};
}
```