# Enumerate enum-instances with loop

Tags: java, loops, coding-style, enums, syntactic-sugar

Scenario:
I want to have an enum containing all the playing cards in a standard deck. For this example ignore the jokers.

Writing

```
enum Cards {
    SPADE_1(0, 1),
    SPADE_2(0, 2),
    etc.
```

feels wrong.

I'd like to be able to do something like this

```
enum Card {
    for (int suit=0; suit<4; suit++) {
        for (int face=1; face<13; face++) {
            new Card(suit, face);
        }
    }
}
```

I've considered defining card as a class containing suit and face fields, where suit and face are themselves enums. However in other scenarios (such as jokers having the suits red and black) this would allow for invalid card objects to be created (ie a joker of diamonds, or a red 10).

Self-answer:
Apparently I don't have enough rep to post an answer to my own question.

> ```
> I'm not sure if it's considered good form to answer my own question, but @Paul just gave me a brainwave.
>
> Declare Card to have a private constructor, and use a
>     static Card getCard(suit, face)
> method to validate combinations before returning them.
> ```

Comment: Perhaps an `enum` isn't what you want.  Do you really need to refer to the 3 of clubs as CLUBS_3?

Comment: Yes, absolutely -- private constructor, separate enums for SUIT and FACE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done using `enum` but we can `implement` `class` as `enum`. you can do something like below.

**Implementations:**

```
public class Card {
    private int suit;
    private int face;

    private Card(int suit, int face){
        this.suit = suit;
        this.face = face;
    }

    public int getSuit(){
        return this.suit;
    }
    public int getFace(){
        return this.face;
    }
    public static Card[] cards = new Card[52];

      static{
        int counter =0;
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<13; j++) {
               cards[counter] = new Card(i, j);
               counter++;
            }
        }
      }
}
```

**EDIT:**
set the `counter` of the card. Earlier it would throw `NullPointerException` for index more than 15.

**USAGES:**

```
System.out.println("face of the card:"+Card.cards[10].getFace());
System.out.println("suit of the card:"+Card.cards[10].getSuit());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
face of the card:7
suit of the card:3
```

Comment: I'd use enums for suit and face, but I think a public read-only collection combined with a get(face, suit) method is the right way to go.

Comment: you can do that either way (using enum or plain class for a card) see the method: public static Card instance(Rank rank,Suit suit) ... in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626670/java-enum-or-encoding-with-numbers/8627079#8627079

Answer (score 0):

I would say make two enums : one for each face, and the other one for each card. So in Card Enum,each enum has two property : number of card ( you can make yet another enum if you don't feel using plain numbers for this purpose), and face which is an instance of face enum. That should solve the problem.

Comment: I would still have to enumerate all 52 cards manually, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I want to reduce amount of source for easier comprehension etc.

Answer (score 0):

i used an enum for rank, suit, and card that seemed to work fairly well. see this answer for the code: [Java: Enum or encoding with numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626670/java-enum-or-encoding-with-numbers/8627079#8627079)

Comment: The tome of finger-hurt you linked to is exactly what I'm trying to avoid