# Create a array list from enums

Tags: java, arraylist

I created two enum classes..

I am trying to create a Arraylist with these two and name it Cards, So.. each color will hold CardTypes.

EX: Four of Red. Three of Red.

I am having some issues on how to do this.

This is in Java, I have tried creating a array with suits and rank and it worked, but for the rest of the code creating with enum is easier.

```
public enum Color
{
   YELLOW,
   BLUE, 
   GREEN,
   RED;   
}
```

AND

```
public enum CardType
{
    ZERO("Zero", 0),
    ONE ("One",1),
    TWO("Two",2),
    THREE("Three",3),
    FOUR("Four",4),
    FIVE("Five",5),
    SIX("Five",5),
    SEVEN("Five",5),
    EIGHT("Five",5),
    NINE("Five",5),
    SKIP("SKIP",0),
    REVERSE("Reverse",0),
    DRAW2("Draw2",0),
    DRAW4("Draw4",0),
    WILD("Wild",4),;

    String Name;
    int Number;
    CardType(String name, int num) 
    {
       Name = name;
       Number = num;
    }
```

}

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: You state that you're trying to create an ArrayList, but we don't see any code with this attempt yet. Please improve your post by showing what you're trying and by using this to help make your question more of a valid question and less of a post of requirements. Please check out the [ask] as well as the [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Create a `Card` class that has a `CardType` and a `Color` field. Add elements of type `Card` to your `List`.

Comment: Do you know about `EnumSet` and `EnumMap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626670/java-enum-or-encoding-with-numbers/8627079#8627079) and do:

```
List l=Arrays.asList(Card.elements);
```

You can also just do: Arrays.asList(Card.values()); if you want the order the cards were declared in.

Answer (score -1):

I expect you need to create separate classes to represent cards and decks that might look something like:

```
class Card {
    private final Color color;
    private final CardType type;
}

class Deck {
    private final List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>() {

    public Deck() {
        for (CardType type: CardType.values()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < type.getCount(); i++) {
                for (Color color: Color.values()) {
                    cards.add(new Card(type, color));
                }
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
    }
}
```